# Linking selenium with electron framework (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron, spectron

I've already written few lines of code in C# using Selenium webdriver. As my application was transferred to the Electron framework everything has changed and honestly, I don't know how to cope with it right now.

Could you please clarify it to me? What steps should I take to simple start... I would like to continue my work in the current project (selenium, C#), but I'm not sure that it's possible, or I should completely start from scratch using a different language and framework?

I've read about Spectron, and checked the internet resources like stackoverflow, however I'm still in the point of unawareness...

Comment: You should try ketlon studio to autome if you are starting from scratch .. it really easy n cool

Comment: selenium automates browsers

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg you are correct but electron app runs on its own chromedriver.so,with some capability added we automate electron app too.But spectron is most suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spectron with mocha is supposed to be faster.

But still here is what you need.This is Java & Selenium.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\electron-chromedriver\\bin\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Users\\app.exe");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
capability.setCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);       
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I have used the packaged electron app for binary (i.e) **app.exe** .

I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Described below is related to using of Electron with .Net C# OpenQA.Selenium.

If you want to run electron app which being developed (consists of files index.html, main.js, etc.) you have to add following options (pay attention to '**app=**' in cmd argument):

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"your_path_to_electron\electron.exe";
options.AddArgument(@" app=path_to_folder_with_your_electron_app_src");
```

But if you want to run packaged electron app (*.exe) it is enough to use:

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = @"path_to_folder_with_your_electron_app\your_electron_app.exe";
```

Also you can start any version of *chromedriver.exe*:

```cs
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path_to_folder_with_driver);
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

It might be helpful because I know that different electron applications are built on using of different version's drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Electron application Initialization:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace Selenium_Demo
{
    class Selenium_Demo
    {

        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Start_Browser()
        {

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32v\\chromedriver.exe",
         @"C:\\Program Files\\Cerebrata\\Cerebrata.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);

            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Close_Browser()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```