# Selenium driver service not starting

Tags: c#, selenium, electron

I am trying to automate testing of an electron application (from third party vendor) using Selenium and C# and am getting the error: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:. Attached is the piece of code.

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1", 
        @"<path to exe of electron application>");
        options.AddArgument("–no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Actual result:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:

Expected Result: driver instance is created successfully

NOTE: The electron application is launched successfully. Also when I remove the path to exe of electron application there is no error and driver instance is created successfully

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136304/linking-selenium-with-electron-framework-c) is the answer, which is working. Think, you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different problems but when I am testing electron apps, I prefer to use following kind of options to set binary. 
Maybe following kind of code block can solve your issue.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(binaryPath);
    options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
    options.AddArgument("–no-sandbox");
    options.AddArgument("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on your inputs I tried below code:



            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1");
            options.BinaryLocation = @"<electron app exe path>";
            //options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);

Comment: This time I got the error:

Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: Can yo please try to put top "-no-sandbox" option. @may04pat05

Comment: Tried this:

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Authoring Suite\OTX Authoring Suite 2.0.exe";
            //options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));

Comment: Got below error:

Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: It is about binary location.  set "@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1" as a binaryPath. @may04pat05

Comment: Okay, but I am trying to test an electron application using the driver. If I provide the binary location as path to chrome driver exe then where should I specify the exe for electron application. Can you please suggest

Comment: You can specify your “-app” argument as a electron app path. @may04pat05

Comment: This does not work for me:

            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1\chromedriver.exe";
            //ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

Comment: Error thrown: Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1\chromedriver.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: This does work for me:

            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            //chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1\chromedriver.exe";
            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32_1");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, chromeOptions);

Comment: To summarize I am not able to set the chrome driver executable path using BinaryLocation but am able to do so using ChromeDriverService. Any help regarding this please ?

Comment: I am sorry but I have no other solution for this.