# Error when trying to use Selenium on Electron app using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and C# to automate the test of an electron app. To start my chromeDriver I use the following code.

```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Analyser-A15\binaries\electron\AnalyserApp.exe";
  string projectDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace(@"bin\Debug\net6.0", "");
  _driver = new ChromeDriver(projectDirectory + @"Drivers\Electron", options);
```

But after  60 seconds I get the following error:

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Mensaje = The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50581/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  Origen = WebDriver
  Seguimiento de la pila:
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   en OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   en BiosystemsBDDCore.Selenium.DriverUtils.SetUpDriver() en C:\Workspace\BiosystemsBDDCore-repo\BiosystemsBDDCore\BiosystemsBDDCore\Selenium\DriverUtils.cs: línea 51
   en AX5Biosystems.Hooks.Hooks.StartDriver(ScenarioContext scenarioContext) en C:\Workspace\AnalyzerSelenium\Ax5BioSystems\Hooks\Hooks.cs: línea 32

Excepción interna 1:
TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.

Excepción interna 2:
TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.

Excepción interna 3:
TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.

Excepción interna 4:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..

Excepción interna 5:
SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

I got this solution from this post [Linking selenium with electron framework (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136304/linking-selenium-with-electron-framework-c)

Also, I tried to add some arguments like this ones:

```
options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
options.AddArgument("enable-automation");
```

But they didn't work. Any clue on what can cause this error? When I use the ChromeDriver on a website it works fine.

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1:50581` as URL ?

Comment: the error appears before the driver is built so I can't assign any URL.  Is there any way to do it on the chromeOptions?

Comment: What is "AnalyserApp.exe" you mentioned in your code? Are you trying to use Selenium for a desktop application?

Comment: As I said it is an electron up