# Can Skype desktop app built on Electron Framework be automated using Selenium?

Tags: c#, automation, electron, selenium-chromedriver, skype

I'm new to Electron Framework.

I'm familiar with Selenium.

Is it possible to automate Skype using Selenium? As Skype is developed on Electron Framework.?

I tried following this article [Linking selenium with electron framework (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136304/linking-selenium-with-electron-framework-c). Below is my attempt.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\Skype.exe";
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
                   
        MessageBox.Show(driver.PageSource);
```

On execution it starts Skype and it loads the splash screen also. But timeouts after 60 seconds with an exception "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50371/session timed out after 60 seconds."

Bellow is the output on the console

```
Starting ChromeDriver 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a5764881c92085aaee66d25075c159aa-refs/branch-heads/5304@{#942}) on port 50371 Only local connections are allowed. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started successfully.


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50375/devtools/browser/5b668094-d32f-483e-8a8d-94b7eb260dd7 [6720:1111/044523.517:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "The Content Security Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' is ignored when delivered via a <meta> element.", source: file:///Index.html (1) [6720:1111/044523.517:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "The Content Security Policy directive 'report-uri' is ignored when delivered via a <meta> element.", source: file:///Index.html (1) [6720:1111/044528.623:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[#01f1280b-S] [WARN] [RootToolsManager] registerListeners: RootToolsManagerDelegate missing setNativeLoggingEventCallback method", source: file:///js/vendor.js (2) Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar\main.js:2:504323
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563 Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar\main.js:2:504323
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563 [6720:1111/044530.143:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[#ffffffff-S] [WARN] [JS.ExceptionHandling] Unhandled rejected SyncTask. Error:  [pii<M...>]", source: file:///js/vendor.js (2) Error occurred in handler for 'keychain:get-password': Error: No stored credentials fetched from keytar.
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for Desktop\resources\app.asar\main.js:2:504323
    at async node:electron/js2c/browser_init:193:563
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with the fact that most built Electron apps disable DevTools access (although I don't know if that has programmatic implications). You could, for a start, try to automate another Electron application (there are plenty) or even try to connect to one you're running from source to eliminate the possibility that there's some mismatch between your ChromeDriver and the Chromium version used by Electron.